# Question about proof that two modules are injectively equivalent.

Tags: modules, injective-module

Assume we have two exact sequences $$0 \to M \xrightarrow{\varphi} Q \xrightarrow{\psi} \mathcal{L} \to 0$$ and $$0 \to M \xrightarrow{\varphi'} Q' \xrightarrow{\psi'} \mathcal{L}' \to 0$$

where $M,Q,Q',\mathcal{L},\mathcal{L}'$ are $R$-modules and $Q,Q'$ are **injective**.

I want to show that $$Q \oplus \mathcal{L}' \cong Q' \oplus \mathcal{L}.$$

My reasoning:

We take note of the fact that if we have $R$-module homomorphisms $$\varphi:M \to Q$$ and $$\varphi':M \to Q'$$ so that we can form the pushout or fiber-sum

$$Y := Q \oplus Q'/\{(\varphi(m),-\varphi(m)\;|\; m \in M \}$$ such that the following diagram commutes

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
M @>\varphi'>> Q'\\
@V \varphi V V @VV \pi_2 V\\
Q @>>\pi_1> Y
\end{CD}.

Now, we look at $$0 \to Q \xrightarrow{\pi_1} Y \xrightarrow{\psi' \circ p} \mathcal{L}' \to 0$$

where $$\pi_1(q) = (q,0)/\sim$$

Now, assume that $$\pi_1(q) = (q,0) =  0/\sim.$$ This implies that there exists an $m \in M$ such that $$(q,0) = (\varphi(m),-\varphi'(m))$$ but since $\varphi'$ is injective, $m$ must be $0$, and then $$(q,0) = (0,0).$$ Hence $\pi_1$ is injective.

Now, I want to show that $$\psi' \circ p:Y \to \mathcal{L}'$$ is a surjection, where $p$ is the projection $$p:Y \to Q'$$ together with the map $$\psi':Q' \to \mathcal{L}'.$$

Now, we know that $$\operatorname{Im}(\varphi') = \operatorname{ker}(\psi')$$ so that an element on the form $$Y \ni (\varphi(m),-\varphi'(m))/\sim \ \overset{\psi' \circ p}{\longmapsto} 0$$ while other elements $$Y \ni (q,q')/\sim \overset{\psi' \circ p}{\longmapsto} \psi'(q')$$ and since we know that $$\operatorname{Im}(\varphi') 
 = \operatorname{ker}(\psi')$$ and we know that we can not have elements on the form $$(0,\varphi(m)) \in Y$$ since this forces $m = 0$ so that $$Y \ni (0,\varphi(m)) = (0,0) \in Y.$$

I believe this atleast argues for a well-defined map (although I am having some trouble showing it conclusively).

Then, since $\psi'$ is surjective, and $p$ is a projection, we get a surjection, and it´s exact at $Y$ (if I am correct).

Then since $Q$ is injective, the sequence splits, and we get that $$Y \cong Q \oplus \mathcal{L}'.$$

I believe one can similarly show, by looking at $$0 \to Q' \to Y \to \mathcal{L} \to 0$$ that $$Y \cong Q' \oplus \mathcal{L}$$ and the statemenent we wanted to prove follows.

Is my idea correct? If not, what is wrong? I am most unsure about that $$\psi' \circ p$$ is a well-defined map, and my argument for it.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: Actually, I think I need to define the projection as $$p:Y \to Q'\setminus \operatorname{Im}(\varphi')$$ otherwise, I don´t think it necessarily will be surjective.

Edit 2: Having thought some more, and reading up, I realize that since $Y$ is an $R$-module, and $\pi_2:Q' \to Y$ is an $R$-module homomorphism (I believe), we can just take the identity map $g:Q' \to Q'$ and then there exists a lift (by injectivity of $Q'$) $$F:Y \to Q'$$ such that $$F \circ \pi_2 = g.$$ Hence I believe I can change $$\psi' \circ p$$ to $$\psi' \circ F.$$

Comment: I would be really happy for specific feedback (about my attempt). @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez.

Am I correct in my edit(2) that I should choose $p = F$?

Answer (score 2):

One way you can organize this so that it becomes readable is as follows.

---

First, suppose that you do the pushout for a pair of maps $A\to B$ and $A\to B'$, so you get a diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>>> B' \\
@VVV @VVV\\
B @>>> X
\end{CD}
Show that if the map $A\to B'$ is injective, then its cokernel and the cokernel of $B\to X$ are isomorphic, and the latter map is also injective.

(You can prove with the benefit of *not* having all the context in your problem laying around. Here you will have to mess with elements, probably)

---

Given that, suppose you have two exact sequences $0\to M\to I\to N\to 0$ and $0\to M\to I'\to N'\to 0$. Then you can do the pushout of $M\to I$ and $M\to I'$, getting the square in the following diagram, which you can then complete by taking cokernels into the following diagram with exact columns and rows
\begin{CD}
{} @. 0 @. 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> M @>>> I @>>> N @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @. \\
0 @>>> I' @>>> X @>>> C @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV \\
{} @. N' @. C'  \\
@. @VVV @VVV \\
{} @. 0 @. 0 
\end{CD}
The observation above tells you that $N\cong C$ and $N'\cong C'$, and if you suppose that $I$ and $I'$ are injective then you know that the middle row and the middle column split and that therefore $$I\oplus N'\cong I\oplus C'\cong X\cong I'\cong C\cong I'\oplus N. $$

(This part of the argument can now be done completely in terms of maps and diagrams, without any need to even touch an element)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. My professor gave me a similar answer (atleast the first part, concerning cokernels). I have not read it in detail yet